# Delphi Indy SSL Error after migrating to 10.4 Sydney

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

After compiling my win32 client/server application (using INDY and TMS Sparkle) with Delphi 10.4 I get an ssl error. I use Indy with and a self signed certificate on the server side and indy on the client side. The error message is (translated from german):

Error connection with SSL. EOF encountered violating the protocol.

I did not change any code or environment from 10.3 where it ran perfectly.  I can break it down to the server side as the old server (compiled in 10.3) runs with the new client (compiled with 10.4) but the old client also breaks when trying to connect to the new server.

This is how I initialize SSL:

```
    SecureServer := TIndySparkleHTTPServer.create(nil);
    SecureServer.DefaultPort := SecurePort;
    // Initialize SSL with self signed certificate
    SSLHandler := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.create(SecureServer);
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := SharedVals.ServerPath + 'appcert.pem';
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := SharedVals.ServerPath + 'approot.pem';
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := SharedVals.ServerPath + 'appkey.pem';
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    SecureServer.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
```

Emba managed to break Indy in 10.3, perhaps this is an other case like this?

Comment: `EOF encountered violating the protocol` means the server closes the TCP connection in the middle of an SSL/TLS handshake. Typically that can happen if the server doesn't like something in the handshake, but OpenSSL will *usually* send an alert to the client before closing the connection. Did you check if your server is raising an uncaught exception after the client connects? On a side note, you really should not be using the `SSLOptions.Method` property at all, use the `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property instead, eg `SSLHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];`

Comment: Embarcadero indeed broke OpenSSL support in Indy in 10.3, but they fixed it, and they just grabbed the latest Indy a few weeks ago for 10.4, and AFAIK there are no known issues with `TIdHTTPServer` or its use of OpenSSL in the latest Indy.

Comment: Thanks, I debugged the server and indeed I get EIdHttpErrorParsindCommand with "Fehler bei der Analyse einer Anweisung" whicht means something like "Error parsig a command" I have no Idea and think Irollback to D10.3...

Comment: `EIdHTTPErrorParsingCommand` is raised when `TIdHTTPServer` receives a malformed HTTP request. Since `TIdHTTPServer` does not process decrypted HTTPS requests until *after* an SSL/TLS handshake has been completed first, that implies that your server is not actually trying to perform an SSL/TLS handshake at all and thus is trying to parse the client's SSL/TLS handshake request as if it were an HTTP request. Is your `SecurePort` set to a non-standard HTTPS port (something other than 443)? If so, make sure your server has an `OnQuerySSLPort` event handler that returns `VUseSSL=True` for that port

Comment: Remy: Thanks once more. I had been using non standard ports and it seems to work by setting vUseSSL to true using a small helper class. To me it seems that  somehow 10.4 doesn't silently default to true here whereas 10.3 did. I saw that this non default port behaviour was already introduced in Indy in 2018 (Atozed Change log).

Comment: The `TIdCustomHTTPServer.DoQuerySSLPort()` method is `virtual`, so `TIndySparkleHTTPServer` can `override` it without using a helper class. As for the HTTPS port behavior, that [behavioral change was made to Indy 2 years ago](https://www.indyproject.org/2018/05/30/behavioral-change-to-https-handling-in-tidhttpserver/). The old behavior was actually a bug performing SSL/TLS handshakes on non-HTTPS ports by default. That was fixed. But it has **always** been the case that if you use non-standard ports then use an `OnQuerySSLPort` handler to make sure HTTP/HTTPS are initialized correctly.

Comment: I needed the class because I used rhe Server Object directly in a DPR and could not assign a non object method. Maybe the key for the fact that it eorked lies in sparkleserver... I will have a look.

Comment: like I said, `TIndySparkleHTTPServer` can `override` the `DoQuerySSLPort()` method directly, eg: `type TIndySparkleHTTPServer = class(TIdHTTPServer) protected function DoQuerySSLPort(APort: TIdPort): Boolean; override; end;` ... `function TIndySparkleHTTPServer.DoQuerySSLPort(APort: TIdPort): Boolean; begin Result := ...; end;` And it is *possible* to use a free-standing function as an event handler, but it requires a hack via the `TMethod` record. Using a non-static class method is preferred.

Comment: Thanks - TSparkleServer is a TMS Product that I use directly in my dpr. I didn't want to modify the source, so I wrote a simple class to assign the method. But what about the hack with TMethod, would you mind explaining that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214898/discussion-between-michaschumann-and-remy-lebeau).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The credit belongs to Remy Lebau who pointed me in the correct direction. But I want to answer my question by supplying the code that made it work again in Delphi 10.4. As the change in Indy was done 2018(!) I still have no idea why it worked perfectly in 10.3 until the upgrade to 10.4.

Since I use the TMS Sparke Server for Indy directly in a service/daemon project I supply a small class to connect the OnQuerySSLPort Method that expects an object method.

```
type
  TSSLHelper = class
  // This helper class is neccessary to set ssl true
  // as it defaults to false on non standard ssl ports
    procedure QuerySSLPort(APort: Word; var VUseSSL: boolean);
  end;

...

procedure TSSLHelper.QuerySSLPort(APort: Word; var VUseSSL: boolean);
begin
  VUseSSL := true;
end;

...

SecureServer := TIndySparkleHTTPServer.create(nil);
SecureServer.DefaultPort := SecurePort;
// Initialize SSL with self signed certificate
SSLHandler := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.create(SecureServer);
SSLHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := SharedVals.ServerPath + 'appcert.pem';
SSLHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := SharedVals.ServerPath + 'approot.pem';
SSLHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := SharedVals.ServerPath + 'appkey.pem';
SSLHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
SecureServer.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
SSLHelper := TSSLHelper.Create;
SecureServer.OnQuerySSLPort := SSLHelper.QuerySSLPort;
...
```

Now it works like before.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just spent 5 hours trying to debug why my app had stopped working after moving from Rio to Sydney. 30 seconds with Google found this and a fix.